# How to find out the user's board id

Tags: api, pinterest

I am new to pinterest, and have limited understanding how thing works in pinterest. Plus i couldn't find an offical API for pinterest.

However i manage to find the following script, which looks like it's going to work for my project.
http://www.nextscripts.com/pinterest-automated-posting

**How its going to work?**
So users just fill in their username and password, and then basically i want to post a image to user's board, but how i am having difficult to know how to get user's **boardID**?

Any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use function doGetBoardsFromPinterest(). It returns the list of all boards for the account.
2. You can just login to your Pinterest.com account look at the source of the Pinterest board page. Board ID will be at the Javascript at the end of the page. It will look like:

var board = 158540918071276794;

Answer (score 3):

@Okapy's "var board" solution does not work any longer. However, if there is an image associated with the board, you can extract the board ID by parsing it:

For example:

```
<meta property="og:image" name="og:image" content="http://media-cache-ec0.pinimg.com/custom_covers/200x150/426153252178994482_1392419088.jpg" data-app>
```

The important part of this is "426153252178994482", which is the board ID.  This can be confirmed by looking through the source of your page for the javascript/json at the bottom which identifies the board via the URL and id in an object, but that's a bit more difficult to parse.

**Update:**

> This answer appears no longer valid as of the moment. One may be able to pull the board ids however I would not recommend it. Example:

```
<script id="jsInit>...</script>
```

Thanks to @wifibrain in the comment below.

Comment: This answer appears no longer valid as of the moment.  One may be able to pull the board ids from the "<script id="jsInit>...</script>", however I would not recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

There's a free tool here

[to get the numberic board id for the user board](http://pinterestboardid.com)

hope this helps. Works most of the times :)

- I contributed to this site.